# Sanitatizing when using the posts_where hook

Tags: sanitization

I am altering the WordPress query, using the `posts_where` hook, when a (custom) query variable is set as follows:

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where' );
function my_posts_where( $where ){
    global $wp_query;

    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['customvar'] )) {
        $custom_Var = $wp_query->query_vars['customvar'];
        $where .= " AND wp_MyTable.Column ='".$custom_Var."' ";
    }
    return $where;
}
```

This works well, but I want to **sanitize** it. In particular, I've tried using `$wpdb->prepare()` method:

```
$where .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND wp_MyTable.Column = %s", $custom_Var);
```

But this doesn't work (I just get a blank page). Why is this and is there another / better way of sanitizing the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `prepare()` snippet should work just fine, check that you have `$wpdb` declared as global in your function.

Also blank page seems extreme, enable `WP_DEBUG` if not yet and see if there are any specific errors that cause it.

Comment: Many thanks Rarst. I could have sworn that is what I had done (and declared $wpdb as global). I had done something silly - maybe an AWOL semi-colon. It works now anyhow, (with $wpdb declared global).